# Microsoft office licence

Tags: microsoft-office

we bought computer from local shop with Microsoft office original. the shop send me this link to download the software and he gave me a product key.

http://down.microsoft-oem.com/office/en_office_professional_plus_2016_x86_x64_dvd_6962141.iso

i want to be sure the license of the microsoft office is original. if i have the product key does it means its original.

how to be sure

best regards

gbu

Comment: "product licensing inquiries" are [expressly off topic here](https://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: `MICROSOFT-OEM.COM` is registered by cheap, low-end GoDaddy. Microsoft.com is registered by Mark Monitor, a very expensive high-end registrar that does trademark enforcement. I'm **very** skeptical that the link you've been given is legit, and would be *very* worried about malware from it.

Answer (score 3):

Update: **Look at the download link. It is not official Microsoft website but a website registered to someone in China. The download may even be virus infected and/or cracked Office. STAY AWAY FROM IT!!**

If you look on ebay, there are too many people selling MS product keys. Most of them will work sometime and give you the impression of having a legit product, but that is not the case. Easiest is to contact Microsoft over chat and ask them about the product key that you received. They will tell you that it is part of some license deal (e.g. educational license with 500 max installation). Once the maximum number of installation is reached, Microsoft will block the key and you will not be able to reinstall your office again.

According to EU law, you are responsible to ensure that you are buying a legitimate product. If the software is used, then you need from all former owner a statement that they removed any old installation and are not keeping copies of the software. If the product is licensed for many users, like Office Professional Plus, you need copy of original license agreement and description of which part of the license agreement you are buying. E.g. if a company has a 10-user license and sells you the 10th user license, since they only need 9 user license, that is legal and fine. But it has to be made clear to you, what you are buying (e.g. the 10th user of a legitimate 10-user license with proof of purchase).

If you are not in the EU other laws will apply to you.

TL;DR
So you can use it, it will work for some time, even updates will work but **most likely** after some time you will not be able to reinstall your office, hence it is **most likely** a stolen license key.

Comment: Update deserves upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

An OEM key for Office will come as a sticker usually or on a card.

The way you seller handled that is strange. Please call the licensing if unsure or call your seller to have the official oem kit

Comment: When you buy directly from Microsoft store, you will not get a sticker but an email with a product key. With that product key you can download the software from Microsoft and install it. The email will proof to you that you have a legitimate product.

Comment: @Pozzo-Balbi I agree, but that does not fit the op scenario, as he used a reseller

Comment: If I buy something from a reseller, it is still my obligation to inspect the product, e.g. ensure I don't get stolen or counterfeit product. Microsoft Office Professional Plus is an enterprise product, hence most likely sold by Microsoft as volume license. Providing a key and download link, even from a reseller, is no sufficient in the EU, it may be different in other countries. I don't see your point stressing "as he used a reseller".

Comment: @Pozzo-Balbi the op send a OEM link. a oem purchase is never an email, and cant be done online that easilly without prooving you just did a pc purchase.

Comment: the above is "NOT" an OEM link. It is a link to a website registered in CHINA. AND Microsoft Office Professional Plus does not exist as OEM version. License questions are off-topic, BECAUSE they are so complex. Hence the end-user MUST apply a good deal of skepticism. So please don't fool yourself by words like "OEM" or "microsoft" in the domain name.

Comment: @Pozzo-Balbi anyway my advise was to call the licensing, so lets end that there